# c language minimum always gets 0

Tags: c

'min' repeatedly outputs zero instead of the actual smallest number. Not sure where i went wrong on this. Any tips would help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int marks,i=0,max,min,sum=0;
    float avg;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {

    printf("iNPUT marks %d:",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&marks);
    sum=sum+marks;
    if (marks>max)
        max=marks;
    if(marks<min)
        min=marks;
    }
    avg=sum/2;
    printf("marks:%.2f\n",avg);
    printf("max:%d\n",max);
    printf("min:%d\n",min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't initialize either `max` or `min` so your code invokes *undefined behavior* by comparing against them

Comment: You need to initialize your variables, to for example `min=INT_MAX` from limits.h.

Comment: What is the initial value of `min`? Try setting that to a very big value.

Comment: Also stop chasing problems that the compiler has already found and told you about. [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Comment: Hmm @Lundin which flag exactly would you recommend in OP's case?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to initialize `min` and `max`.

As a result when you compare `marks` again those two variables, the values of `min` and `max` are garbage, invoking *Undefined Behavior*.

Change this:

```
int marks,i=0,max,min,sum=0;
```

to this:

```
int marks, i = 0, max = INT_MIN, min = INT_MAX, sum = 0;
```

Those macros require you to include `limits.h` library.

---

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int marks, i = 0, max = INT_MIN, min = INT_MAX, sum = 0;
    float avg;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("Input marks %d:", i + 1);
        scanf("%d",&marks);
        sum=sum+marks;
        if (marks>max)
            max=marks;
        if(marks<min)
            min=marks;
    }
    avg=sum/2;
    printf("marks:%.2f\n",avg);
    printf("max:%d\n",max);
    printf("min:%d\n",min);
    return 0;
}
```

Which for input 1 and 2 gives:

```
Input marks 1:Input marks 2:marks:1.00
max:2
min:1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing `min` and `max`.
The code invokes Undefined Behavior when you compare `mark` against both variables (containing garbage).

Also you can change the loop initializing min and max during the first iteration:

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    printf("iNPUT marks %d:",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&marks);
    sum=sum+marks;
    
    if(i==0){ // First iteration both values are the same
       max=marks;
       min=marks;
    }
    else{
       if(marks>max)
           max=marks;
       if(marks<min)
           min=marks;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi jCres. I think your approach will work. However I'd prefer to initialize them before getting inside the body of the for loop in order to avoid introducing one unnecessary if-else statement, which of course won't make any difference in performance now, but in greater, real-world projects - if followed as a practice - may reduce readability and hurt performance (branching prediction in compilers).

Comment: You are right, your solution is better performance-wise.